# Is my app running on the Blackberry Simulator?

Tags: testing, blackberry, java-me, blackberry-simulator

I am testing a blackberry app that sends SMS messages.  I would like to use the simulator for testing, but since SMS doesn't work on the simulator I would like to have an alternate code path to handle the interaction.   What is the right way to detect that the app is being run under a simulator, instead of an actual device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DeviceInfo.isSimulator()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/DeviceInfo.html#isSimulator())